# how to get data from a long text with regular expression

Tags: php, regex, websocket

Below is a long text in which the value of `broadcast_id` and `user_id` present in that text. As you can see on the first line.

```
GET /?broadcast_id=27&user_id=10 HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: http://localhost
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 2QEMNVrk7PdivBxc+sO+
```

I want to get the broadcast_id value as 27 and user_id value as 10 from above text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex for grabbing these 2 values:

```
(broadcast_id|user_id)=([^&\s]+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nK8kK0/1)

**Code:**

```
preg_match_all('/(broadcast_id|user_id)=([^&\s]+)/', $input, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Thank you anubhava.Please explain me how that works.